# Google Spreadheets Scripts: check if cell is empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cell, spreadsheet

I want to input a variable in a cell only if the cell is empty. The if statement, however, does not work. Any advice?

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var r=ss.getRange("'odpovědi'!A2:J");

var rws=r.getNumRows();

ax=r.getCell(rws-1, 10).getValue();

if (ax == "") {
  ax = "foo";
  r.getCell(rws-1, 9).setValue(ax);
}
```

Comment: You have column 10 on one line, and 9 on the other, so those are two different cells. A typo. Otherwise it works as intended.

Answer (score 52):

No need to extact the value to determine if the cell is empty. Google Spreadsheet API already has a method for this: [Range - isBlank method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isBlank())

```
var cell = r.getCell(rws-1, 10);

if (cell.isBlank()) {
    cell.setValue("foo");
}
```

Comment: does this method `isBlank()` has a negation? Line `cell.isNotBlank()`.

Comment: No, so only option available is to use the _negation symbol_ like: `if ( !cell.isBlank() )`

Comment: suppose, from my row range,  first  five row is not blank but t last three rows are blank, then what to do ?   sh.getRange(2, 1, 8, 26).getValues(); ? how to check For blank ?

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getSheetByName('odpovědi')
  var lr=s.getLastRow()  
  var ax=s.getRange(lr, 10).getValue();
     if(ax == ""){
        ax = "foo";
        s.getRange(lr, 10).setValue(ax);
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

If you already have cell value then use `===` or `!==` operators if you want avoid type conversion (where `0 == ""` ).

Code snippet for decreasing not empty cell values

```
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];     
var range = sheet.getRange("E2:H5");
var currentValues = range.getValues();  

var newValues = [];
for (var row in currentValues) {
  var newRow = []; 
  for (var col in currentValues[row]) {
    if (currentValues[row][col] !==  "") { // if not empty cell
      newRow[col] = currentValues[row][col] - 1;          
    }
    else {
      newRow[col] = currentValues[row][col];
    }
  }
  newValues[row] = newRow;
}    
range.setValues(newValues);
```

Comment: Upvoting this because it's super-useful to know that empty cells are represented as an empty string `""` in the array returned from `getValues()`