# how to ask a question in forms appear only if there is something in a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to make question 5 appear only if cell F1 is not empty.

```
//Question5 test
var Title = setupSheet.getRange('F1');
if( Title == "" ){
}
else {
  form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
  .setTitle(setupSheet.getRange('F1').getValue())
  .setChoiceValues(setupSheet.getRange(2,6,setupSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues());
}
```

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: this is not working, the question keeps appearing empty in the google form

Comment: `var Title = setupSheet.getRange('F1');` only defines the range; it doesn't return the value.. You need something like `var Title = setupSheet.getRange('F1').getValue();` that can evaluate the contents of "Title". You might also look at [Google Spreadheets Scripts: check if cell is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41664971/1330560) to see some options for testing for the existence of "Title".